# How can I know the events from onBeforeInput and onInput are based on the same event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, textarea, onchange

How can I know the events from onBeforeInput and onInput are related?

```js
export const MyApp = () => {

    const onBeforeInput = (eventBefore) => {
        console.log(eventBefore)
    }

    const onInput = (event) => {
        console.log(event)

        const eventBefore = getEventBefore() // how can i get eventBefore here?
        console.log(eventBefore)
    }

    return (
        <textarea onBeforeInput={onBeforeInput} onInput={onInput}/>
    );
}
```

How can I use the associated `eventBefore` inside `onInput`?

---

Comment: I am asking because I need to use `selectionStart` from `eventBefore` inside `onInput`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Store the `eventBefore` in a variable common to both functions

If you create the variable in an environment that encloses both functions, they should share a single variable:

```
export const MyApp = () => {

    let theEventBefore = null

    const onBeforeInput = (eventBefore) => {
        theEventBefore = eventBefore
        console.log("theEventBefore being set to:",theEventBefore)
    }

    const onInput = (event) => {
        console.log(event)
        console.log("theEventBefore being read as:",theEventBefore)

    }

    return (
        <textarea onBeforeInput={onBeforeInput} onInput={onInput}/>
    );
}
```

#### `beforeInput` will finish before `onInput` starts, as long as `beforeInput` is synchronous

Javascript is single-threaded, so unless you are using promises, or async/await, etc, you can be sure that `beforeInput` will complete first.

Once the `beforeinput` event has completed, the browser will process the user input and *then* fire the input event.

Comment: Thank you, but doesn't this also presume that `onInput` always finishes before subsequent `onBeforeInput` is triggered? But I guess that is guaranteed since Javascript is single-threaded?

Comment: If this presumption were to be false, i guess it could risk that `onInput` would use an updated `eventBefore` event, rather than the 'correct' old `eventBefore`,  which would be unwanted behaviour.

Comment: Yes, so keep the `onBeforeInput` code synchronous. This is straightforward to achieve if it is only using local data and doesn't have to send out a request to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that using `onKeyDown` is better then using `onBeforeInput`, since `onBeforeInput` does not trigger on backspace.